# How to set up HP wireless scanner in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer, scanner

I have the HP DeskJet 3835 connected to my local network.

I installed the printer using the Windows Printers & Scanners settings:

[image]

But then when I open Windows Scan, the scanner isn't listed. It apparently recognizes the device only as a printer, not a scanner:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after removing the device and re-adding it, it's now recognized as a scanner as well.

HTH